# Upload an xml database to google app engine

Tags: xml, google-app-engine

I have a Xml file which contains a lot of data. I would like to know how I could get this data into the google app engine platform? Is there any way I can simply upload the entire file to google app engine?

Answer (score 0):

You could upload the file to [Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/) but if you need to treat your data I'd parse the xml and write the entries to [Google Data Store](https://developers.google.com/datastore/).